# Doctrine2 EntityNotFoundException when getting an entity from relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In a Symfony2 project using Doctrine2. I have a Lead entity related with Promotion entity 1-N. A Lead con have a related Promotion or not.

```
//Lead.php
...

/**
 * @var string $promotionCode
 * @ORM\Column(name="promotion_code", type="string", length=16)
 */
 private $promotionCode;

/**
 * @var Promotion $promotion
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Promotion")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="promotion_code", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $promotion;
...

public function setPromotionCode($promotionCode) {
  $this->promotionCode = $promotionCode;
}
public function getPromotionCode() {
  return $this->promotionCode;
}
public function setPromotion($promotion) {
  $this->promotion = $promotion;
}
public function getPromotion() {
  return $this->promotion;
}
```

When I want to obtain the related promotion (if any) y do

```
$lead = $em->getRepository('BuvMarketplaceBundle:Lead')->find($id);
$promotion = $lead->getPromotion();
```

If the lead has a promotion this is OK. But if not this code returns a Promotion "entity", but when I try to use if I get an EntityNotFoundException.

So I have to test if the related promotion exists like this:

```
if (is_object($promotion) && method_exists($promotion, 'getDiscount')) {
  try {
    $promotion->getDiscount();
  } catch(EntityNotFoundException $e) {
    $promotion = null;
  }
} else {
  $promotion = null;
}
```

I know that I can use a findBy in the Promotion Repository, and may be another methods to check this.

**But the question is if this is a bug or a feature in Doctrine2**, so I'm getting a "false entity" when I think it may be a null.

Comment: Show the code for Lead::getPromotion();  It really should just return null if there is no promotion.  You got something else going on.

Comment: Just added sone more code about the fields used in the relation. As you can see I don't have any additional code in the getters.

Comment: How do you retrieve your Lead Entity?

Comment: I use the find() method from the repository.